# Audiokit Control interaction capture

Tags: audiokit

I'm trying to capture synth pitch/volume/e.t.c changes along the duration of an AKSequence, i.e it records changes to AKMidiNoteData as its playing, Im thinking I should have a slider or wheel on my instrument ui and start capturing slider/wheel positions every 1/256 second or so, once a user has started manipulating them, is that the right way to go about this? Are there existing tutorials for this?

Comment: There are no tutorials for that but your initial approach sounds like a good start.